# Caesar Cyper Python

Tags: python

```
def caesar_encript(txt, shift):

chiper = ""
for i in range(len(txt)):
  char = txt[i]
  
  if char == " " :
      chiper += ' '
  elif (char.isupper()):
     chiper += chr((ord(char) + shift - 65) % 26 + 65)
  elif (char.islower()):
     chiper += chr((ord(char) + shift - 97) % 26 + 97)

        
return chiper

def caesar_decript(chiper, shift):
    return caesar_encript(chiper, -shift)
 

msg = 'Random Mesage, WOOOWW!'
cpr = caesar_encript(msg,4) 
txt = caesar_decript(cpr,4)

print('plain text : ', txt)
print('chiper text : ', cpr)
```

I made a code for encryption but the output does not display special characters and I want special characters to be displayed without encryption

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A crude solution would be to replace this

```
if char == " " :
    chiper += ' '
```

with this

```
if not char.isalpha():
    chiper += char
```

Answer (score 0):

The special characters are not considered because they're also being encrypted. This approach places an if condition before that where `isalnum()` decides only alpha numeric characters to become encrypted.

```
def caesar_encript(txt, shift):
    chiper = ""
    for i in range(len(txt)):
        char = txt[i]
        
        if not char.isalnum():
            chiper+=char
        else:
            if (char.isupper()):
                chiper += chr((ord(char) + shift - 65) % 26 + 65)
            elif (char.islower()):
                chiper += chr((ord(char) + shift - 97) % 26 + 97)
```

**Output**

```
plain text :  Random Mesage, WOOOWW!
chiper text :  Verhsq Qiweki, ASSSAA!
```

Comment: That's a complicated structure. It can just be an `else` to the `isupper`/`islower` conditions...

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand. Did you mean the `else` wasn't required and the `isupper/islower` could come as `elif` condition?

Comment: It's hard to post code as comment, but what I meant is that it can just be: `if char.isupper: chiper += ... elif chat.islower: chiper += ... else: chiper += char`. Hope that makes it clear

Comment: Oh yes got it. But won't this condition ignore messages with numbers in it? I know that the current code is meant for characters only but if such a case arises, it won't be encrypted.

Comment: I'm not sure numbers are encrypted in Caesar cypher. Should be clarified by the OP